# Authentication in Slack

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, slack-api, slack

I have already generate test tokens to sign in to my Slack account from the following link; https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-test-tokens

When I use API Methods, I add the token to URL.

Now I want to integrate users accounts.  Are they going to generate test tokens from this url and I will get that generated tokens? I don't think so. Not so practical.

How can I authenticate them? By getting their username and password and basic Node.js https call with BASIC Authentication as it is in; https://dzone.com/articles/nodejs-call-https-basic

When I read the documentation for authentication it suggests; https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth 
Should I get all information; client_id, scope, redirect_uri, state, team from the user? How will they know their client_id?

How can I sign in to users account in the Slack integration? I'm little confused..

Comment: The `client_id` is for your app. It's not different for different users, so they don't need to "know" anything. You just send them to the authorization page at Slack, they click the button to authorize your app, and they're redirected to you with an authorization code. I'd recommend doing some research on OAuth 2. It's not specific to Slack, and lots of good guides exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to authenticate Slack users with your external app you should use Sign-In with Slack. It will prompt the user to sign in to their Slack team with username and password and return their Slack identify to your app. You will also receive an individual Slack token which you can store for future use if you want to keep users "signed-on".

See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack) for a great explanation on how this feature works.

If you just want a bot or slash command to work with your Slack team, you don't need to authenticate each user. The token you receive after using the "Add to Slack" workflow will be sufficient. Also, The "test token" you can generate on the Slack API page will work. However, this "shortcut" is only supposed to be used for testing.